# How do I restore the public key?

Tags: wallet, private-key, public-key

Let say, I create wallet and have two public key and one private key.

And I remove the first public key from the wallet.

Can I restore and use my first key again? Or it's removed at all.

Sorry for the maybe a silly question I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new wallet (in any recent software) a new seed is generated, from which all the private key / address pairs are generated (there cannot be an address without its specific private key); usually Bitcoin clients don't let you remove addresses from wallet, but even if you manually delete one or all of them, if you backed up your seed, you can re-generate all addresses you have used (and in the same order), since all modern wallet are hierarchical deterministic.

Here a more detailed description of how the HD wallet work: [learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/hd-wallets](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/hd-wallets)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have only one question Bitcoin Core doesn't ask the seed phase. Is it mean it doesn't support HD? It asks for a password only.

Comment: Yes, Bitcoin Core use HD wallets by default, but it don't use the mnemonic seed so you can't backup the wallet with the words list but you must backup the file wallet.dat. you find more info on this answer: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/91819/117651